# Getting ValidationException when saving DynamoDB entity using Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I am working with SpringBoot application that does CRUD operation on aws dynamoDB, and I have entity class that has structure of the following

```
// getter, setter, args, no args annotation here
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "TableName")
public class Entity {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "PartitionKey")
    private String key; 

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "SortKey")
    private String tempSortKey; 

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Value")
    private String tempValue;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "TerminationDate")
    private Date tempTerminationDate;
 
    // bunch of other variables and attributes


// Repository

public Entity savEntity(Entity entity) {
    dynamoDBMapper.save(entity);
    return entity;
}

// Controller
//Controller Class
@PostMapping(value="URL")
    public Entity saveItem(@RequestBody Entity key) {
    return Repository.saveKeyValue(key);
```

I get an error and the error message is: "Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AmazonDynamoDBvZ; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException".

I have made sure that PartitionKey is of type string and sort key is not selected when dynamoDB was first created and I do not have access to either create or modify the table. Other thing I tried was to change the entity class like so

```
// getter, setter, args, no args annotation here
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "TableName")
public class Entity {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "PartitionKey")
    @DynamoDBAUtogeneratedKey
    private String uniquekey; 

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="key")
    private String key;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "SortKey")
    private String tempSortKey; 

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Value")
    private String tempValue;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "TerminationDate")
    private Date tempTerminationDate;
 
    // bunch of other variables and attributes
```

This works fine but I do not want Autogenerated unique key. I also need Sort key within Table as key might have similar values but sort key will always have unique value.

I also tried having key on two different variable one as HashKey and one as Attribute and that works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have made sure that PartitionKey is of type string and sort key is not selected when dynamoDB was first created and I do not have access to either create or modify the table

My understanding is that you're trying to include a sort key in your data model using annotation `@DynamoDBRangeKey` however your actual table was not creates with a sort key and you have no permission to alter/create a new table. Feel free to correct me if I misunderstood.

You're seeing a validation exception as you cannot just add a sort key to your data model of your actual table has not defined one. You need to re-create your table should you wish to include a sort key in your data model.

> Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided

https://repost.aws/articles/ARPPEPfTPLTlGLHIsVVyyyYQ/troubleshooting-unable-to-unmarshall-exception-response-with-the-unmarshallers-provided-in-java